# DB visualizer tool, not able to show data while run sp

Tags: dbvisualizer

Issue in using dbvisualier tool:
While sp can be executed, no result output showing up.  This SP is tested ok to show data with others DBvisualizer. 
by simply testing sp_helptext, its not able to showing output with notification as :

> 17:37:15  [SP_HELPTEXT - 0 row(s), 0.167 secs]  Command processed. No
>   rows were affected Code: 0 SQL State: 010P4 --- 010P4: An output
>   parameter was received and ignored. ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0
>   row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.167/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1
>   warnings, 0 errors]

-It may not be issue with my logins or accounts permission, as i have tested and compared with FID. 
-It may not be issue due to my DB visualizer version, as my colleague who has same version works fine, and i have upgraded to most recent version but still not working. the certification is new.
-I have also compared DB Visualizer tool properties with colleague who works fine, nothing different.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server or Sybase are you using and what version of DbVisualizer? I suggest you enable debug mode of DbVisualizer in Tools->Debug Window and then re-run the SP. Once executed open Help->Contact Support to send the log to the DbVisualizer support team.

Comment: its not only a issue with sybase, but all DBs i configured used in this tool